# Round values in column from floats to ints using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to round values in column from floats to ints using Python

**Data**

```
    location    a site   b site   c site
    aa          4.9000   1.72222  0.29999
    bb          5.9000   6.72222  0.46999
```

**Note**
I do not wish to round down on c site 0.29999

**Desired**

```
    location    a site   b site   c site
    aa          5        2        1
    bb          6        7        1
```

**Doing**

```
df[list("a site", "b site", "c site")] = df[list("a site", "b site", "c site")].astype(int)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: I'm still baffled as to why np.ceil returns a float when the documentation says: "The ceil of the scalar x is the smallest **integer** i, such that i >= x. It is often denoted as ." There's probably a reason, but I'm not clever enough to figure it out! https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `np.ceil` round

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes(np.number).apply(np.ceil))
df
  location  asite  bsite  csite
0       aa    5.0    2.0    1.0
1       bb    6.0    7.0    1.0
```

Comment: Better not to avoid `apply()` wherever possible as it's not vectorized and is therefore very slow. In this case, np.ceil can be used directly on both a single column and on a df, as shown in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.ceil`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html) to round up, and then convert the floats to integer using `astype(int)`.

```
import numpy as np

df[["a site", "b site", "c site"]] = np.ceil(df[["a site", "b site", "c site"]]).astype(int)

>>> df

  location  a site  b site  c site
0       aa       5       2       1
1       bb       6       7       1
```

Comment: ah ok thank you, I forgot to add the brackets to signify columns.

Comment: @Lynn no problem, glad to help! Note that using `np.ceil` directly (instead of passing it to `apply`) is faster, especially if you are dealing with large data.